# Debian 8.0 minimal IPtables Persistent not loading on boot

Tags: debian, iptables

For my company we are working on a phone system that is running on a Debian 8.0 minimal VPS hosted at Wable.com.

Everything was working great until some of us had some home network changes and the server started locking us out.

I would try to ssh into the server and it said that the connection was refused on port22. So i went into the console on Wable.com and added my IP to the whitelist for IPtables and then I could ssh in and stuff like that. But upon exiting the console on Wable.com a reboot occurs and the changes made to IPTABLES get flushed out.

I attempted to follow this post here https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently

to make sure that the changes made to Iptables would load on boot. This did not work. I am pulling hair out trying to figure this out.I am reaching out here in hopes that I can achieve success with our phone system.

Our company is at a standstill without phones.

This is the printout when i enter `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                       
target     prot opt source               destination              
fail2ban-fusionpbx  all  --  anywhere             anywhere        

fail2ban-freeswitch-dos  all  --  anywhere             anywhere   

fail2ban-freeswitch-udp  all  --  anywhere             anywhere   

fail2ban-freeswitch-tcp  all  --  anywhere             anywhere   

fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             m
ultiport dports ssh                                               
fail2ban-fusionpbx  all  --  anywhere             anywhere        

fail2ban-freeswitch-dos  all  --  anywhere             anywhere   

fail2ban-freeswitch-udp  all  --  anywhere             anywhere   

fail2ban-freeswitch-tcp  all  --  anywhere             anywhere   

fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             m
ultiport dports ssh                                               
ACCEPT     all  --  cpe-104-34-107-159.socal.res.rr.com  anywhere 

ACCEPT     all  --  cpe-172-89-5-182.socal.res.rr.com  anywhere   

ACCEPT     all  --  cpe-172-89-5-182.socal.res.rr.com  anywhere   


Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)                                     
target     prot opt source               destination              

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                      
target     prot opt source               destination              

Chain fail2ban-freeswitch-dos (2 references)                      
target     prot opt source               destination              
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 

Chain fail2ban-freeswitch-tcp (2 references)                      
target     prot opt source               destination              
REJECT     all  --  cpe-172-89-5-182.socal.res.rr.com  anywhere   
          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable                       
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 

Chain fail2ban-freeswitch-udp (2 references)                      
target     prot opt source               destination              
REJECT     all  --  cpe-172-89-5-182.socal.res.rr.com  anywhere   
          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable                       
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 

Chain fail2ban-fusionpbx (2 references)                           
target     prot opt source               destination              
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 

Chain fail2ban-ssh (2 references)                                 
target     prot opt source               destination              
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Would you please clarify why it does reboot once you get out, some clue about the changes, and if you made all the steps documented in the doc?

Comment: made all the steps in the document. I am not sure why it automatically reboots. It may be the way that the console is set up from the VPS provider.

Comment: Hey Rui, I added a printout of iptables -L so that you can see what is happening. I think it has to do with the fail2ban freeswith tcp and udp rules

Comment: let me try to understand, you are basing your fail2ban whitelists in your dynamic IPs at home, right? And the thing started to fail when they changed?

Comment: please post the [ssh] section of /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

Comment: [ssh]                                                             

enabled  = true                                                   
port     = ssh                                                    
filter   = sshd                                                   
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by fail2ban whitelists. All that I know right now is that when I try to ssh into the server from my pc on wifi i cannot. I can ssh into the server from my smartphone running on cell network. I cannot register with the PBX system from my laptop but from my cell network I can register and make calls.   A co worker whose home network recently changed configuration and introduced ipv6 from ISP also cannot make calls

Comment: `grep "ignoreip" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` too please.

Comment: You made a cut&paste of a comment of mine by mistake.

Comment: # grep "ignoreip" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf                
# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail
2ban will not                                                     
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8

Comment: confusing. Please `grep "^ignoreip" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`

Comment: # grep "^ignoreip" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf               
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8

Comment: are private messages possible on here? if you would like to help in real time we can have a skype?

Comment: they are, thing is already 0000am here and no more in my notebook. I would suggest you guys using freedns for the machines involved to give them a permanent dns name, and adding that  dns names to the ignoreip list. in a while i can elaborate on this in a proper answer. cannot be IPs address as they are roadrunner and change over time, and freedns is a free service

Comment: that sounds like a viable option. I would like to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fail2ban is blocking your own accesses, either to a low threshold or something else. Nevertheless, the best strategy is to add your own machines to an exception list, so they are not blocked automatically by fail to ban.

However, as we have seen with your iptables, you are using residential addresses that are prone to change.

As the IP addresses will change more or less frequently, the best idea is to use a Dynamic DNS service. There are several, and some are free too. Through running a binary or a script in the machines that use your services, a DNS name given by that service is mapped to that machine.

I do advise creating one account with FreeDNS https://freedns.afraid.org
After you create an account, you can create entries for each machine that will map it to a new domain, like pc1.mooo.com, pc2.mooo.com, pc3.mooo.com.  (There are a few domains from which you will be able to choose) When you select the pages, they also have a section that explain how make the call to get a page.

With that, you will be able to edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`and modify the line:

```
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 pc1.mooo.com pc2.mooo.com pc3.mooo.com
```

and then

```
sudo service restart fail2ban
```